# Calculate datatime difference between rows in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the datetime difference between rows for each unique machine_id here. I have already grouped the Dataframes and have tried

```
newdf = newdf.copy()
newdf['diffs'] = float('nan')
newdf = newdf.copy()
for index in newdf.index.levels[0]:
    newdf.diffs[index] = newdf.event_datetime[index].diff
```

the dataset looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg93C.png

Comment: What package are you using for your dataframe?

Comment: I'm using pandas

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `diff` after groupby operation? Something like:

```py
newdf.groupby('machine_id').event_date.diff()
```

Comment: HI, yes. I have tried it. But the problems is event_data has a type of datetime. I'm trying to find a way to calculate the difference between two datetime variables

Comment: I think `diff` works with datetime also. What is the dtype of your `event_date`? And what is your desired output? Differences in days, hours, seconds (integers) or just timedelta?

Comment: yes, the diff function should work fine even the type is datetime. Maybe you should set your variable into datetime using pd.to_datetime

Comment: Hi, my desired output is differences in days, hours and seconds.

Comment: @RunyaoYin then you can try converting your target column to datetime first `df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])`

Comment: I have done that. it is not shown on the picture because the Dataframe has too much columns

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create multi index data frame, it should work fine using `diff()` function.

using `newdf.groupby('machine_id').event_date.diff()` suggested by ATL should work fine.
o

```
# hierarchical indices and columns
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[598, 615, 721], [43, 43, 45]],
                                   names=['machine_id', 'prod_category_id'])

# mock some data
data = ['2017-03-20 12:00:00','2017-03-29 01:00:00','2017-04-29 01:00:00',
        '2017-03-30 02:00:00', '2017-04-29 02:00:00','2017-05-29 12:00:00',
        '2017-10-30 02:00:00', '2017-11-29 02:00:00', '2017-11-29 04:00:00']

# create the DataFrame
newdf = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
newdf.columns = ['event_date']

newdf['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(newdf['event_date'])
newdf.groupby(level=0)['event_date'].diff()
```

[image]